# What could be changed for service designer / developer / operating manager when a company implement DevOps Approach?

Tags: devops

I study DevOps now and just understand the difference between waterfall and devops, its effect and benefits.

My question is What could be changed for service designer / developer / operating manager when a company implement DevOps Approach?

It is saying that when devops approach is implemented, developer group and operation group should have more conversation for CI/CD but I cannot find any more detail information.

I don't have any some kind of project, so please let me know what will be changed for each group of IT department.

If there is a guidance for implementing devops and guidance for desinger/developer/operating manager, it will really be helpful.

thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd recommend taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as an introduction to how SO works, and how to effectively ask questions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would like to turn your attention to "waterfall and devops" comparison - these are apples and oranges.
Waterfall can be compared to agile (scrum, kanban, etc) but not to DevOps.
Waterfall is a code delivery frequencty approach. But DevOps is a culture.

What will be changed for **developer**:

His code will be executed exactly in the same environment as he expects to. Whether it is dev, test or prod - it will run in the same container within the same environment variables (only physical resources like CPU/RAM/HDD can differ).
Thus, it significantly decreases the risk to fail in production and subsequently decreases the need to connect to production for investigation.

What will be changed for **operations** (SRE, system admin):

He gets code with described environment [read more about Infrastructure as code (IAC)] and he doesn't care what dependencies, operation system or whatever it has. All he needs to serve: abstract layer beneath the code (like Kubernetes, for example). And this layer does not depend of code state, thus the work scope of operations guys are better planned and do not depend of milestones or whatever.

What will be changed for **manager**:

He has better predictability in his forecasts, as bugs now appear no that frequently because same container that was in test goes to production. Also troubleshooting takes more predictable time as microservices much easier to troublshoot like electrical chain.